# How to concatenate streams?

Tags: shell, pipe, cat

I know `cat` can concatenate files, but I need to concatenate a mix of files and *streams* and pipe the result to another process.

To make the question more concrete, I want to concatenate `cat abc.sql` together with `gzip -dc xyz.sql.gz` and `cat qvf.sql` and pipe it all as a single stream to `mysql`.

What's the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just use a subshell, e.g.

```
(cat abc.sql; gzip -dc xyz.sql.gz; cat qvf.sql) | mysql
```